# Queued Tasks at a specific time

Tags: c#

So, I've got a WCF application that accepts requests to do work at a specific time.  I could have a list of thousands of things to do in the future at varying times.  Is there an existing framework that we can leverage to do this?  The current implementation polls a database, looking for things to do based on a datetime, which smells.

A few ideas.

1. Timers.  Set a timer when the request comes in that fires are the appropriate time.  This seems like I could have too many threads floating around.
2. Maintain a list of objects with a datetime in memory, poll this for things to do.
3. Use a library like quartz.  I have concerns as to whether this can handle the volume.

Comment: Why not use something like `NServiceBus` to queue tasks?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a list of tasks sorted by their trigger times (Your database should be able to do this without any issues. If you want to keep it in-memory, [Power Collections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) has a priority queue you could use), you can get by with a single timer that always activates for the first one in the list.